# Как сделать, чтобы со страницы без параметра грузилось на страницу с параметром =1?

Tags: url, php, yii

```
'rules'=>array(

    'page/update/<id:\d+>'=>'page/update',
    'page/<id:\d+>/<page:\d+>'=>'page/view',

),
```

Тоесть у меня есть юрл вида `/page/165/1`, хотелось бы чтобы юрл понимал такую `/page/165` страницу точно так же.

Comment: .

    'page/<id:\d+>' => 'page/view',

...

    class PageController extends CController
    {
        public function actionView($id, $page=1)
        {
            //...

Comment: а так он портит ссылки и они становятся вида  /page/165/?page=1

Comment: .

    'page/<id:\d+>/<page:\d+>'=>'page/view',
    'page/<id:\d+>' => 'page/view',

Comment: то есть мне надо и меду съесть и ....
Чтобы ссылки были с номером страницы когда надо , т.е. /page/165/2
И чтобы с 1 страницы ссылка была /page/165
Просто как не пытался он либо забивает на второй парраметр либо делает вот так как сейчас

Comment: У меня пример выше спокойно работал. Но вообще еще можно писать 

    'page/<id:\d+>' => 'page/view/page/1',

И при создании ссылаться на роут `'page/view/page/1'`

Comment: да так работает!) спасибо огромное. Вот я немного не понимаю, вот этот роут 'page/view/page/1' означает , что мы берем контроллер page действие view и парраметр page? 
Проблеммы у меня возникают с виджитом pagination он не рисует хорошие ссылки, теперь в нем ссылка на первую страницу вот такая http://graduate.vzmakh.ru/page/view/id/165 =)

Comment: @Yii_TRATATA, это незадокументированный способ, я про него случайно узнал. Вернусь - посмотрю точнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот вполне работает в Yii 1.1.14

```
'rules' => [
    'page/<id:\d+>/<page:\d+>' => 'page/view',
    'page/<id:\d+>' => 'page/view/page/1',
]
    ...

echo $this->createUrl('page/view', ['id' => 12, 'page' => 1]); // /page/12/1
echo $this->createUrl('page/view/page/1', ['id' => 12]); // /page/12
```

Comment: плохо только с виджетом pagination, он почему то первую ссылку выдает 
"/page/view/id/165" она кстати рабочая, в любом случае вышло почти, что хотел, ещё раз спасибо.